# Creating an UnsafeMutablePointer<UnsafeMutablePointer<Float>> parameter in Swift 3

Tags: swift, signal-processing

The Swift signature of the Accelerate framework `vDSP_biquadm()` function includes parameter types of `UnsafeMutablePointer<UnsafePointer<Float>>` and `UnsafeMutablePointer<UnsafeMutablePointer<Float>>`.

How does one declare and create such types in Swift 3, and then fill these pointer arrays with references to several Swift arrays of type `[Float]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you need to pass multiple values for `UnsafeMutablePointer<T>` parameters, you need to declare a variable of type `[T]` (aka `Array<T>`) and pass it as an inout argument. In your case `T` is `UnsafeMutablePointer<Float>`.

So, if you want to start with `[Float]`, you may need to write something like this:

```
let input: [Float] = [/*...*/]
var output: [Float] = Array(repeating: 0, count: outputTotalSize)
input.withUnsafeBufferPointer {inBuf in
    let inputPtr = inBuf.baseAddress!
    output.withUnsafeMutableBufferPointer {outBuf in
        let outputPtr = outBuf.baseAddress!
        var pInputs: [UnsafePointer<Float>] = [inputPtr,/*...*/]
        var pOutputs: [UnsafeMutablePointer<Float>] = [outputPtr/*...*/]
        vDSP_biquadm(setup, &pInputs, inStride, &pOutputs, outStride, length)
    }
}
```